# Pagination with custom filtering Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

When creating custom filtering based on ACF fields, pagination stopped working. That is, it works, but when the filter is applied, it does not update the pagination of articles, but uses the pagination as if all articles were displayed. I have already tried the standard pagination options

````
<?php
    $free = $_COOKIE['free_article_val'];
    $block = $_COOKIE['block_article_val'];
    $bought = $_COOKIE['bought_article_val'];

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);


    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $its_free_post_value = PostFilter::Its_free_post();
            $bought_post = PostFilter::Its_bought_post();
            if ($its_free_post_value == 1 && $free !== 'true_val' && $_SESSION['start_session_val'] == 1){
                continue;
            }
            if ($bought_post == 1 && $bought !== 'true_val' && $_SESSION['start_session_val'] == 1){
                continue;
            }
            if ($bought_post == 2 && $block !== 'true_val' && $_SESSION['start_session_val'] == 1){
                continue;
            }
            biagiotti_mikado_get_post_format_html( $blog_type );
        }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем переменную $post
    }else{
        biagiotti_mikado_get_module_template_part( 'templates/parts/no-posts', 'blog' );
    }

    ?>
</div>

<?php
previous_posts_link( 'Prev page ' );
next_posts_link( ' Next page', $query->max_num_pages );

PostFilter::Check_session(); ?>```
````

Answer (score 0):

To start with as step 1, this is incorrect

```
'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1
```

I would replace it with

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```